# Unity3d Touch input doesn't work in webgl

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a webgl build and trying to do zoom in/out and it doesn't work in webgl build on mobile phone while testing.

```
 private void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Disable();
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        controls.Touch.SecondaryTouchContact.started += _ => ZoomStart();
        controls.Touch.SecondaryTouchContact.canceled += _ => ZoomEnd();
    }
    private void ZoomStart()
    {
        ZoomCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ZoomDetection());
        isTouch = true;
    }
    private void ZoomEnd()
    {
        StopCoroutine(ZoomCoroutine);
        Debug.Log("zoom end");
        isTouch = false;
    }

    IEnumerator ZoomDetection()
    {
        float previousDistance = 0f, distance = 0f;
        while (true)
        {
            isTouch = true;
            Debug.Log("zoom");

            distance = Vector2.Distance(controls.Touch.PrimaryFingerPosition.ReadValue<Vector2>(),
            controls.Touch.SecondaryFingerPostion.ReadValue<Vector2>());
            //detection
            //Zoom out

            if (distance > previousDistance)
            {
                cameraTransform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(cameraTransform.position, targetGameObject.transform.position, -1.0f * 0.5f);


            }
            // zoom in 
            else if (distance < previousDistance)
            {
                cameraTransform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(cameraTransform.position, targetGameObject.transform.position, 0.5f);

            }


            // keep track of previous distance for next loop
            previousDistance = distance;
            yield return null;
        }
```